# Unable to use javascript to open a dialogbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using a simple javascript to open a dialogbox in asp.net

```
<script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
     function openDialog() {
         var result = window.showModalDialog("", "", "dialogWidth:300px; dialogHeight:201px; center:yes");
     }
 </script>
```

and Used it in

But Get a Error Message 
Error   5   'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'openDialog' and no extension method 'openDialog' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In First parameter you need to pass URL / Page, which you are going to display as DialogBox

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>

function ShowDialog()
{
    //declare a string variable
    var retval="";

    //show modal dialog box and collect its return value
    retval=window.showModalDialog
    ('dialogboxhostframe.htm',window);

    //check if user closed the dialog 
    //without selecting any value
    if(retval!="" && retval!=null)
    {
        //fill the textbox with selected value
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").value=retval;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for Response But I still get same error Error 1 'ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ShowDialog' and no extension method 'ShowDialog' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: When will you use this script to open dialog. means button click or what?